# Oracle APEX 5.1 - How to sort selected values in a Shuttle control

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a shuttle control with a list of countries. So the user can select multiple countries, example: `UK, France, Portugal`. The order depends on how the user selects or moves the choices (see pic)

[image].

These are stored as `UK:France:Portugal` in the underlying table.

The problem is that I need these countries to be stored alphabetically because UK:France:Portugal is not the same as `France:Portugal:UK`. I know that in an ideal world these are saved in separate rows, but unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Is there a way to sort the selected values within the shuttle (on the right) alphabetically, maybe through a dynamic action when selecting countries?

If not, as an alternative, can we have a Post Calculation Computation to sort and store these values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know *Apex-solution*, but I can suggest *Oracle-solution*.

Here's an example: table `test` stores information about countries:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, countries varchar2(30));

Table created.
```

A database trigger sorts values in the `countries` column. How? It splits colon-separated values string into rows (that's what the `regexp` and `connect by` do), and then merges them back into another colon-separated values string (using `listagg`), but this time sorted (`order by 1`):

```
SQL> create or replace trigger trg_biu_cou
  2    before insert or update on test
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    select listagg(regexp_substr(:new.countries, '[^:]+', 1, level), ':') within group (order by 1)
  6    into :new.countries
  7    from dual
  8    connect by level <= regexp_count(:new.countries, ':') + 1;
  9  end;
 10  /

Trigger created.
```

OK, let's see it work:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, countries) values (1, 'UK:France:Portugal');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID COUNTRIES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 France:Portugal:UK

SQL> update test set countries = 'New Zealand:Croatia:Hungary' where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID COUNTRIES
---------- ------------------------------
         1 Croatia:Hungary:New Zealand

SQL>
```

Might be OK; give it a try.

Comment: Excellent idea! It does the job just as well, thanks a lot. Of course if there's anyone that knows how to do this in APEX without resorting to triggers, that would be welcome too.

Comment: You're welcome. If you have some time to spare, you could try to apply that (trigger) code to Apex.